# Is numpy.zeros has limitations in "accepting" variable/matrix name? It isn't declaring errors but variables are not registered using the same code

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I was just creating zero arrays using np.zeros:

```
XMI= np.zeros((50,1))
```

I tried this code to different names X, ABC, XM, B, C5, XMI but only X, B and C5 are saved/registered/accepted in the variable list. I am wanting to use the array name XMI, XCR. Please help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `numpy.zeros`. You had some other bug.

Comment: What is the *variable list* that you say doesn't list the variable?

Comment: I don't think there's other bugs because I just literally changed the variable name which are not yet used in any part of the code.

Comment: ABC, XM, XMI aren't listed on the variable list/explorer. Anyway, I just stick to some naming and my code worked already. Thanks!